# JS Tree Selecting un selected items

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, jstree

I am using JsTree checkbox which contains lot of sub fields.

When I am selecting one field it automatically selects the sub category of another field.

So that field shows partially checked.

> For instance:
>
> In my JsTree When I clicked "United States" it partially selects
>   "Canada".

Please any one explains this behavior.

Since the tree is big I am not pasting the code instead of that I am posting an JsFiddle URL.
Code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#tree").jstree({
        "checkbox": {
            "keep_selected_style": false
        },
            "plugins": ["checkbox"],
                                'core': {
                                    'data': {
  "id": "ALL",
  "text": "ALL",
  "children": [] ...
```

> JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/1r70vjmx/

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: Duplicate ID's

**Long answer**: The jsfiddle example shows some nodes having a duplicate ID. jsTree requires that you have unique ID's for all nodes throughout your tree data. In your data, Ontario city in the United States and the Ontario province in Canada have the same id 'Ontario'. If in this case you apply a prefix of 'us-' to all the id's for United States you will see that the problem disappears.